# How to view session details in php using firebug?

Tags: php, session, console, firebug, firephp

I'm trying to figure out I how can do something like:

```
console.log('<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>');
```

To see the results in the console.

```
console.log('<?php echo serialize($_SESSION); ?>');
```

does not work either.  Is there a way for me to echo the session information in firebug or inspect element in chrome for testing purposes?

Comment: are you using this code between script tags?

Comment: Not working does not qualify as a correct description about the error you face. You can not just throw anything out as javascript "string" and then expect it to work. Imagine there is a `'` inside the serialized string, it would just make it stop working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this :

```
<script>
    console.log(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>);
</script>
```

No quotes are required. See as well [Firebug and Logging](http://getfirebug.com/logging).

---

[edit, May 2014] Updated the code to be safe against XSS attacks. *Always* pass `JSON_HEX_TAG` to `json_encode` if you're embedding in HTML, or an attacker could inject code into the DOM by having you encode a string like:

```
</script><script>alert('Hello!');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to view the session details using fire bug.

Comment: Actually this answer is pretty correct by its nature and doesn't deserve to be downvoted, since it is really not possible to view the session data using only firebug - your serverside should prepare the data. And in this case the question makes no sense, because you can prepare anything: data from session, db, 3rd party service, etc

Comment: In Chrome it's easily accessible under the Application tab. Is this still missing from Firebug? I understand that I could view it on server side, but it'd be easier to see it like in Chrome.